# Powershell run with C# cannot call samba

Tags: c#, powershell, samba

I'm having trouble executing commands by running Powershell in C#.

```
powerShellProcess1 = new Process();

powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
powerShellProcess1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
powerShellProcess1.OutputDataReceived += PowerShellProcess1_OutputDataReceived;
powerShellProcess1.Start();
powerShellProcess1.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

I ran Powershell as above and send the command as below, but it does not execute.

```
string samba_loc = SambaLocationBox.Text + " -p ";
string com_port = "serial:" + COMPORT_1.Text + ":115200 -b ";
string set_info = "sama5d27-som1-ek -a sdmmc:0:1:0:8:4 -c ";
string file_loc = "write:" + FileLocationBox.Text + Environment.NewLine;
string powershell_cmd = String.Concat(samba_loc, com_port, set_info, file_loc);

powerShellProcess1.StandardInput.WriteLine(powershell_cmd);
```

Powershell called from C# runs other programs except sam-ba.exe well.
Commands are also executed well.
Only sam-ba.exe does not run.
(Version information of samba I use: sam-ba_v3.7-rc2-win32)

Suspecting a permissions problem, I configured the app in administrator mode and ran Powershell, but there was no improvement.

Please tell me what kind of stupid thing I'm doing.

Comment: Is there a reason you're launching powershell to execute a program, rather than executing that program directly? Can you provide a [mre] - for instance, what is the value of `powershell_cmd`?

Comment: In response to the requirement that it is inconvenient to enter commands directly, Powershell is called from C# to configure the UI.

".\sam-ba.exe -p serial:COM11:115200 -b sama5d27-som1-ek -a sdmmc:0:1:0:8:4 -c write:.\sama5d27_emmc-202306252324-mmcblk0.direct" The purpose is to send it, but even if just send .\sam-ba.exe to cmd, sam-ba.exe doesn't even work.

Comment: What does "to configure the UI" mean? What do you mean "doesn't even work"? Do you get an exit code? Is `sam-ba.exe` something you made or something you got from the OS/other party? Have you been successful in executing the exe in a terminal, outside of C#?

Comment: I created a project as a Windows form in C#, opened Powershell as Process, and connected it to RichTextBox.
And, sam-ba is a program distributed for Windows.
Lastly, sam-ba.exe runs normally outside of C#, but does nothing when run inside. As if no command was ever entered.

Comment: II agree with @gunr2171 and would suggest starting the sam-ba process directly (so `var proc = new Process(); proc.StartInfo.FileName = SambaLocationBox.Text;` etc.). If you are unwilling to do that, what kind of output are you getting from the powershell process? Something like `powerShellProcess1.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` might give you some hints what the actual problem is

Comment: Ah, I understand. I struggled with the trap of having to use Powershell. God bless you.

Comment: It would still be interesting to know why PowerShell would/could not run `sam-ba.exe`.

Comment: sam-ba.exe is a tool distributed by microchips and can be found at the following link.
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/sam-ba-in-system-programmer
I tried calling this directly as a Process and realized that it still doesn't work in C#.